# Apache httpd won't stop doing reverse DNS requests for clients' IPs

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, httpd, reverse-dns

Obviously my Apache httpd instance is doing reverse DNS (RDNS, give me the hostname for this IP address) lookups for each incoming client connection's IP address. This is bad. Especially since sometimes resolution fails with a missing PTR record - **after 28secs**.

Diagnostics: I added `%D` to my "combined" log style and looked at the response times this way: Clearly <1s for all those that are logged with their hostname and 20+s for those that get their IP logged.

This is what I tried:

- Turn off the `server-status` extension.
- Check that `HostnameLookups Off` is in the config.
- Check that `mod_access` is not given any hostname in an `Allow`/`Deny` rule.
- Check that reverse proxied servers follow the same rules.

What have I missed?

Comment: Restart apache after the changes?

Comment: Yes I did, though `force-reload` was enough.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It seems the standard Ubuntu 8.04 Apache httpd install comes with a [`LogFormat`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat) that starts with `%h` and that does a client IP's RDNS lookup. Why oh why?? Replacing it with `%a` (remote IP address, see [custom log formats](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats)) reduces this problem by ca. 90%. Some remain...

Answer (score 3):

Have you verified `HostnameLookups` is not set in any other directive?
Have you activated the module mod_authz_host?

Comment: Yes I `grep -ri`-ed it all over. `mod_authz_host` is active and no hostnames are used in the Allow/Deny-rules. Now not even with `localhost`.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled over the same problem and I discovered another source of reverse lookups: the applications themselves! PHP has the `gethostbyaddr()` function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, I just ran into a similar issue on one of my servers.  The problem started right around the time I ran a command-line PHP script that scanned the log files for the top IP addresses.  Then I had PHP perform a reverse DNS lookup on each IP address.  Right around the time I did this, I noticed that Apache suddenly started dumping hostnames into the logs instead of IP addresses.  Switching to %a from %h and restarting Apache seems to have cleared up the problem.  HostnameLookups is set to Off.  My guess is that Apache just uses locally cached results if there happens to be a reverse lookup for the IP in the cache.  Maybe?  Either that or this is a bug in the server.

Answer (score 0):

I have an apache server behind an NGINX reverse proxy server. Apache server would do a reverse DNS lookup for every request. I tried everything suggested so far, and even went as far as commenting out the log lines, but Apache (or something) was doing reverse DNS lookups (of the NGINX server). I then added the NGINX server in the apache server's `/etc/hosts` file and no more reverse lookups! While all this was happening Apache would happily forward the remote-ip (of the client) without any lookups. Happy with the workaround, but would love to know how to completely avoid lookup of the same NGINX reverse proxy server, over and over again!